# I was invited to give a conference talk: What should I ask beforehand?

Tags: conference, presentation

I recently gave a talk at one international (virtual) conference, a couple days later I was invited to give a talk to another (virtual) conference. The scope of the second conference is more localized both geographically and on the topic and it is in 4 months.

I would like to learn and interact with members of the organization behind the second conference, so I have accepted their invitation. We are now discussing the topic of my talk.

Maybe they are being polite, but they insist on me asking any question I might have. Is there anything I should be aware before the conference? What is important to know before the conference starts?

Comment: + How much time I have? 
+ Who's my audience? 
+ Who are the other speakers? (To avoid topic overlapping)
+ Will the talk be recorded? (It is not important I guess but a possible question to ask) 
+ Is there a backup solution in case of Internet disconnection? (for example pre-recorded videos)

Comment: @Younes Your comment could well make an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible questions I could think of:

- **How much time do I have for the presentation and how much time remains for discussion?**
- **Who's my audience?** It is good to know what would be interesting for your audience.
- **Who are the other speakers?** (To avoid topic overlapping; if you know that Prof. X who is an expert in Y will give a talk, you would choose a different topic because it is highly likely that X will give a talk in that area)
- **Will the talk be recorded?** (If you want to publish it on your own blog/channel)
- **Is there a backup solution in case of internet disconnection?** (for example pre-recorded videos). I attended a conference a few weeks ago where the invited speaker -voluntarily- pre-recorded his presentation in case he cannot make it live.
- **When and at what time my talk will take place?** (In case it is not decided yet and you want to plan other things)

**EDIT (relevant for offline events)**

- What will I be expected to pay for/what are the organisers willing to cover/waive? (Meeting registration? Abstract fees? Travel + accommodation?)

Comment: Less relevant to virtual conferences, but: What will I be expected to pay for/what are the organisers willing to cover/waive? (Meeting registration? Abstract fees? Travel + accommodation?)

Comment: @avid If you don't mind, I would add it to the answer!

Comment: Many thanks for the quick comment and answer, on their first message they already provide an audience description. I found the duration time looking at their past conference schedule and they confirmed already the time. I asked for the other speakers but they are still checking which other keynotes can present. I'm not specially bothered on the time of the talk, but good points about the technical side. Would it be impolite to ask if I can participate of the whole conference?

Comment: @llrs "Would it be impolite to ask if I can participate in the whole conference?" I would say the opposite because it shows interest in the conference.

Comment: Ask about copyright and the implications of it if you want to use this in future.